# Ionic5 typescript, how can i tell my html its html code [innerHTML] not work

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

i am a nooby in ionic5(typescript) hope u can help me
The code in my Html is:

`[innerHTML]="jsondataservice.storageCards[1].l_content " id="last"`

### he still shows me the html tags such as (</ br <div etc)

I've read that it might work with my own pipe somethink like that

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  sanitizer: DomSanitizer;

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }

}
```

i tryed but i cant find my pipe in html with

````
 [innerHTML]="jsondataservice.storageCards[1].l_content |safeHtml" id="last"```

pls help >-<
````

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from "@angular/platform-browser";
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  sanitizer: DomSanitizer;

 
transform (value: string): SafeHtml {
    let lTextArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    lTextArea.innerHTML = value;
    return lTextArea.value; 
    
}
}
```

```
<div  [innerHTML]="jsondataservice.storageCards[1].l_content |safehtml" id="last" ></div>
```